# How to Stop Tkinter Program When Using a Class

Tags: python, tkinter, destroy, mainloop

I'm using python to create a class object that controls a Tkinter window. My code looks like this:

```
class MyGui:
    
    def __init__(self):
        
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.title("My Gui")
        
        return
    
    def makeButton(self, text, on_click_function, should_pack = True):
        """ Makes a button widget """
        
        button = tk.Button(self.root, text=text, command=on_click_function)
    
        if should_pack:
            button.pack()
    
        return button
    
    def start(self):
        
        self.root.mainloop()
        
    def stop(self):
        
        self.root.destroy()
```

I want to be able to start an instance of the class, then stop it like so:

```
a = MyGui()
a.makeButton('STOP', a.stop)
a.start()
... // OTHER CODE HERE EVENTUALLY // ...
```

Everything works fine and the window is successfully created on `start()` and it vanishes when the button is clicked and `stop()` executes. The issue is that the mainloop continues to run. I have to manually kill the program using Ctrl+C and it shows it being killed at `self.tk.mainloop(n)`.

If I just do all my tkinter code in a normal file rather than a class, everything works the same but the mainloop also stops when I call destroy on root, and the program ends. If I put it in a class, however, mainloop doesn't stop in spite of the window being destroyed.

Why? How can I get it to stop mainloop too? (I can stop the whole program by calling `sys.exit`, but I want to keep executing non-Gui stuff after I call `stop` via the button-press).

Comment: `self.root.quit()` ?

Comment: Do you want to stop the program from an event (like a button press) or after a set amount of time?

Comment: Both, actually. I want to be able to push a button and let the mainloop be quit, or to have it quit on its own after a certain amount of time.

Comment: Also code execution stops at `a.start()` and doesn't reach `a.stop()` until the `mainloop` stops

Comment: Why would code execution stop at start()? It would run start() then keep going, and then hit the stop() command... I used ..//.. to show there would be other code in the middle, but perhaps that's confusing.

Comment: @Elliptica When creating a button inside the class just use `command=self.close`. If you want it to quit on its own after 10 seconds use: `self.root.after(10000, self.close)`. That will schedule a call to `self.close()` after 10000 milliseconds (which is 10 seconds)

Comment: @theLizzard If I try that, I get `AttributeError: 'MyGui' object has no attribute 'close'`.  If I try it on `root`, I get `AttributeError: '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'close'`.

Comment: @Elliptica My bad. Instead of `self.close`, it should be `self.stop`. I misread your code :D

Comment: @theLizzard, yes that is what I do. Perhaps I should just show the button code. I'll update in one sec.

Comment: @Elliptica Move the `a.makeButton('STOP', a.stop)` before the `a.start()`. After you call `a.start()`, nothing will be executed until the window is closed.

Comment: @TheLizzard, silly me, it's before a.start() in my code but I inserted it wrong here. I've updated the question.

Comment: @Elliptica If you click the button, it should close the window, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234974/discussion-between-elliptica-and-thelizzard).

Answer (score 0):

I figured out I can solve the problem if I put `self.root.quit()` and `self.root.destroy()` together in the `stop()` function, but not if I use them separately (using just `destroy` closes the window but leaves the mainloop running; using just `quit` cancels the mainloop but leaves the window open and in a weird state that causes crashing when you try to close it manually).

So the class function actually needs to look like this:

```
def stop(self):
    
    self.root.quit()
    self.root.destroy()
```